# Linq XML query - How do I return a node that meets a condition within its own nested nodes?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following xml structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<administrators>
   <administrator>
    <fullname>full name1</fullname>
    <email>email1@email.com</email>
    <provinces>
      <province>3</province>
      <province>9</province>
    </provinces>
  </administrator>
  <administrator>
    <fullname>full name2</fullname>
    <email>email2@email.com</email>
    <provinces>
      <province>1</province>
      <province>2</province>
    </provinces>
  </administrator>
</administrators>
```

I want to be able to return administrator nodes that have particular province nodes.  I have tried the following:

```
IEnumerable<Administrator> admins = RootElement.Elements("administrator")
        .Where(x => x.Elements("provinces")
                .Any(p => int.Parse(p.Element("province").Value) == provinceId))
        .Select(x => new Administrator()
        {
            FullName = x.Element("fullname").Value,
            Email = x.Element("email").Value
        });
```

and my result set is empty.

So what am I missing here?  if provinceId = 3 how do I select the administrator element that has a province element that equals provinceId?

Comment: Actually, are you trying to return administrator XElements, or construct equivalent Administrator objects?

Comment: You have a typo - missing "r": RootElement.Elements("administ*R*ator")

Comment: @František: I think you've solved the problem. Post that as an answer!

Comment: Not quite, it would still not work - having the condition constructed like it is in `Any` - parsing value of `p.Element("province")` makes it check only the first `province` child of `provinces` element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good case for using XPath:

```
  RootElement.XPathSelectElements("//administrator[provinces/province = '" + provinceId + "']");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<Administrator> admins = RootElement.Elements("administrator")
    .Where(x => x.Elements("provinces")
            .SelectMany(p => p.Elements("province"))
            .Any(p => int.Parse(p.Value) == provinceId))
    .Select(x => new Administrator()
    {
        FullName = x.Element("fullname").Value,
        Email = x.Element("email").Value
    });
```

(I have not yet tested this.)

Answer (score 0):

```
    var admins = RootElement.Elements("administrator")
.Where( a => a.Descendants("province").Any( p => int.Parse(p.Value) == provinceId ) );
```